# Getting "SyntaxError: Unexpected token" in Observable

Tags: javascript, vega-lite, vega, observablehq

I was trying vega-lite-api on observablehq [here](https://observablehq.com/@bf1b3c8dfdc6c9e9/untitled).

This is my code:

Putting these two in different cells work:

```
obj = vl.markPoint()
  .data(df)
  .encode(vl.y().fieldN('city'));
```

In next cell:

```
obj.render()
```

If I put both in the same cell, it [gives `SyntaxError: Unexpected token`](https://observablehq.com/@bf1b3c8dfdc6c9e9/untitled#cell-22):

```
obj2 = vl.markPoint()
  .data(df)
  .encode(vl.y().fieldN('city'));

obj2.render();
^
```

Why is this so?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put the code into the same cell, you can either chain the call to render like so:

```js
vl.markPoint()
  .data(df)
  .encode(vl.y().fieldN('city'))
  .render()
```

Or you can use a block cell with curly braces like so:

```js
{
  const obj = vl.markPoint()
    .data(df)
    .encode(vl.y().fieldN('city'));

  return obj.render();
}
```

For more on Observable JavaScript:

https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/observables-not-javascript

Comment: **Q1.** But we cannot make it print json and render in the same cell, right? That sounds somewhat stupid, I guess... **Q2.** Also why the way I did (no chaining and no block cell) in the question as shown in [this](https://observablehq.com/@bf1b3c8dfdc6c9e9/untitled#cell-21) cell doesnt work? Does it violate some basic JS syntax / principle? (Seems that I miss something basics here...)

Comment: No, a cell can only display one output (have only one value), so you can’t have the cell’s value be both the Vega-Lite Mark instance and the rendered chart itself. The basic thing you might be missing is that Observable isn’t vanilla JavaScript—it’s a dialect of JavaScript with a concept of cells. This is explained in the article I linked. If you want two values, use two cells. (Or use the viewof operator, but that’s a more advanced topic.)

Answer (score 0):

for obj you have a definition before you use it...

```
obj = N {
  Symbol(data): Object {mark: h, data: Object, encoding: h}
  <prototype>: N {}
}
```

I guess you forgot about it for obj2?